# How to push to the same UIViewController instance every time?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, segue, unwind-segue

In Storyboard I have a `UINavigationController` connected to the `rootViewController`, which has a *custom* push segue to one more `UIViewController` and a *custom* pop segue back. I'm trying to **instantly** (no animation, iOS8) move back and forth between the two VCs without recreating the destination VC again and again.

Here are the custom segues:

```
@implementation PushNoAnimationSegue

// This is a hack!    
static UIViewController *dvc;

-(void)perform {
    if (!dvc) {
        dvc = [self destinationViewController];
    }
    [[[self sourceViewController] navigationController] pushViewController:dvc animated:NO];
}
```

and

```
@implementation UnwindNoAnimationSegue

-(void)perform {
    [[[self destinationViewController] navigationController] popToViewController:[self destinationViewController] animated:NO];
}
```

The above work as intended in this simple scenario, but of course the `PushNoAnimationSegue` is using a hack, plus some destination VC is always `alloc`'d, which I want to avoid. **How can this be achieved without an ugly hack?**

Comment: Where's the ugly hack? I'm not a big fan of static variables most of the time, but if you truly do want to *always* push the same view controller instance then maybe it's the simple solution. What problem do you foresee with your "hack"? More specifically, what would you like to improve about your current implementation?

Comment: @Caleb "Where's the ugly hack?" --> The Segue itself is maintaining a reference to a VC. Pretty ugly. Next, a VC is always alloc'd and discarded - wasteful. Finally, how to release this VC under low memory pressure, or on demand etc? I'm sure you're not advocating this approach.

Comment: Ideally, I'd like to instantiate the second VC once, then switch back and forth between the two VCs instead of push and popping while still using a custom segue.